# Recordar usuario y contraseña

Tags: login, activity

Hola tengo un login y un checkbox y quiero usarlo para que me recuerde el usuario y la contraseña como podria hacerlo?

Aqui dejo el login activity:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText email, password;
private Button sign_in_register;
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
private static final String URL = "";
private StringRequest request;
public CheckBox ch;
public static final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "user_pass_pref";


@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    sign_in_register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    ch = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

    if(ch.isChecked())
    {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("username", email.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("password1", password.getText().toString());
        editor.apply();
    }
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    String restoredText = prefs.getString("username", null);
    if (restoredText != null) {
        String name = prefs.getString("username", "");
        String password1 = prefs.getString("password1", "");
        email.setText(name);
        password.setText(password1);
    }


    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    sign_in_register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        if (jsonObject.names().get(0).equals("success")) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SUCCESS " + jsonObject.getString("success"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + jsonObject.getString("error"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    hashMap.put("email", email.getText().toString());
                    hashMap.put("password", password.getText().toString());

                    return hashMap;
                }
            };

            requestQueue.add(request);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza SharedPreferences, yo lo he realizado así y funciona (Ignora lo de VolleyDataSource). Aquí lo explica muy bien de todos modos http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/preferencias-en-android-i-shared-preferences/

```
private Button iniciarSesion;
private EditText email, password;
private SwitchCompat switchCompat;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.signin);

    iniciarSesion = findViewById(R.id.btn_iniciarSesion);
    email = findViewById(R.id.txt_signin_email);
    password = findViewById(R.id.txt_signin_password);
    switchCompat = findViewById(R.id.switch_signin);

    final SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("recordarmeWallet", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String emailtext = prefs.getString("email", "");
    String pass = prefs.getString("password", "");
    boolean stateSwitch = prefs.getBoolean("stateSwitch", false);
    switchCompat.setChecked(stateSwitch);
    email.setText(emailtext);
    password.setText(pass);

    iniciarSesion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if(switchCompat.isChecked()){

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putString("email", email.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("password", password.getText().toString());
                editor.putBoolean("stateSwitch", switchCompat.isChecked());
                editor.commit();

            } else {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putString("email","");
                editor.putString("password", "");
                editor.putBoolean("stateSwitch", switchCompat.isChecked());
                editor.commit();
            }
            VolleyDataSource.getInstance(v.getContext() , 10).checkLoging( email.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza [`SharePreferences`](http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/preferencias-en-android-i-shared-preferences/) para almacenar el usuario y contraseña.

Para guardar has esto:

Define una variable estatica con el nombre de la preferencia:

```
public static final String = MY_PREFS_NAME = "user_pass_pref";
```

Luego cuando quieras guardar has lo siguiente:

```
if(checkbox.isChecked())
{
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("username", email.getText().toString());
 editor.putString("password", password.getText().toString());
 editor.apply();
}
```

Entonces para leerlos en caso de que vaya a hacer login otra vez:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
if (restoredText != null) {
  String name = prefs.getString("username", "");
  String password = prefs.getString("password", ""); 
  username.setText(name);
  password.setText(password);
}
```

Actualizacion:

Estas guardando el usuario y contraseña cuando inica el activity y deberia de ser cuando se haya clic a login:

```
 //...

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //...

    sign_in_register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(LoginActivity.this.ch.isChecked())
            {
                // guardas el usuario y contraseña cuando se haya hecho clic sobre el boton
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putString("username", LoginActivity.this.email.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("password1", LoginActivity.this.password.getText().toString());
                editor.apply();
            }

            //...
```

Comment: me da error en MY_PREFS_NAME

Comment: no hace nada, hay algo mal? he subido el codigo con el sharedpreferences

Comment: no me guarda los datos de usuario y contraseña

Comment: como si no hubiese hecho nada

Comment: lo mismo, sin hacer nada

Comment: acabo de actualizar el codigo, miralo, creo que lo he sustituido como me has dicho

Comment: Lo que pasa es que estas guardando el usuario/contraseña cuando carga el activity y deberias de guardar los datos cuando se haga clic y el login haya sido exitoso.

Comment: Mira la respuesta actualizada.

Comment: Perfecto Gracias!!!!